# Channel not found error in - Spring BlazeDS Integration

Tags: apache-flex, spring, configuration, blazeds

I'm trying to convert a simple chat Java/BlazeDS project over to the new Spring BlazeDS setup.

I started fresh and copied in the **blazeds-spring** folder contents in the blazeds 4 turnkey distro which added a few new files

```
web.xml
flex-servlet.xml 
spring/
    app-config.xml 
    infrastructure-config.xml 
    security-config.xml
flex/
    services.config
```

services.config now has removed references to messaging, remoting and proxy configs. 
My flex swf is compiling against this services-config.

```
<services>
    <default-channels>
        <channel ref="my-polling-amf" />
    </default-channels>
</services>
```

my flex-servlet.xml contains

```
<flex:message-broker>
    <flex:message-service
default-channels="my-streaming-amf,my-longpolling-amf,my-polling-amf" />
    <flex:secured />
</flex:message-broker>

<flex:message-destination id="chat" />
```

The problem I have when I launch the swf is this message

**[MessagingError message='Destination 'chat' either does not exist or the destination has no channels defined (and the application does not define any default channels.)']**

Does someone know where its looking for this destination and if anything appears incorrect from my setup?

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure that you are using the correct filename. The default location/filename for the BlazeDS XML configuration file is:

> /WEB-INF/flex/**services-config.xml**

see [*Configuring the MessageBroker in Spring*](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch02s03.html)